# How can I add color to events in the .ics Google Calendar files?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

As of now, I managed to create an .ics file from a text file that has my work schedule, now the issue is that I would like to distinguish morning and night shifts with colors.

It's possible in the site itself, but it's a daunting task to change them all manually, so, if there is a line i can insert programmatically, I would include it to be written in my autoit script.

Is there such a line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original ICS format (see [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-81)) has no concept of color.

There is an update in [RFC 7968](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7986) that adds color support:

> **Property Name:**  `COLOR`
>
> **Purpose:**  This property specifies a color used for displaying the calendar, event, todo, or journal data.
>
> …
>
> This property specifies a color that clients MAY use when presenting the relevant data to a user. Typically, this would appear as the "background" color of events or tasks. The value is a case-insensitive color name taken from the CSS3 set of names, defined in Section 4.3 of [W3C.REC-css3-color-20110607].

However, for Google Calendar events with custom colors, no such information is written in the exported files. This means that Google uses its own database to store colors for calendar events.

It would be easier to create two different calendars and set their color in the software that displays them.